# Why wont the docker service start?

Tags: 19.10, services, docker

When I type `sudo service docker start` I get this error:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The output of `systemctl status docker.service` is

```
 docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-03-29 23:13:17 PDT; 13s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 15795 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 15795 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 29 23:13:17 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and the output of `journalctl -xe` is `Mar 29 23:24:29 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2112]: wlx00c0ca97fef3: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS` over and over again except the time is different in each line

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this problem I had to **disconnect from my VPN.**

Running `sudo dockerd -D` had revealed that there was a networking error.

(This is on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: thanks, that runs the validation which will highlight any issue, including parsing the daemon.json.